# Promise with self executing anonymous function - TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefine

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to call function 3&4 after 1&2 have fully executed.

```
(function(){
    function1();
    function2();
})().then(function(){
    function3(); 
    function4();
})
```

Comment: Are these functions async?

Comment: The error is self explanatory. Your anonymous function returns `undefined`...

Comment: @nikhilagw yeah

Comment: @plineon - the answer below must have fixed the issue for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) & use `.then` to chain it.In this case the function will be executed in 1,2,3,4 in order

```js
function function1() {
  console.log('1')
};

function function2() {
  console.log('2')
};

function function3() {
  console.log('3')
};

function function4() {
  console.log('4')
};


(function() {
  return Promise.resolve(function1()).then(function2)
})().then(function3).then(function4)
```